# Unable to wget the file from linux terminal

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, wget, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to download a file from S3 bucket. The link of the URL is a presigned url. I can able to download the S3 link via web browser but unfortunately it doesn't apply for the linux terminals. Below is the sample link.

> https://prod-04-2014-tasks.s3.amazonaws.com/snapshots/054217445839/rk12345-414a7069-c29e-42b7-8c46-2772ef0f572d?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoDYXdzELz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDJxH5NWcgw1QYX4nXCK3AwhdbSSQNGC8Ph4Uz7gqhfJssILaqIA008aYoH4Ycs7JMs92wE2Rg4h6uQJ7TW3mYyiBJgctM4Ku%2FzpxFdBM0qBnMCEhCMxnIUkYoaQOMN1EJrRzKkAXPlhjn2dAiWMmrCQ189C5GyCDkAJHQeRkBu%2B9hH4tWhnBuSCTRzcdftu04ArNDgJ5jIy0F5cCVOAuBvZEsS4Ej1gHFJW5GY2PDzaXyktQGvz9Uk5PgPo11PPWUlbPet9ASCvaUB5z7o%2Bwg9w9Ln8wV4oMnOFT4zG4toYoArp9lP61vCkJjIvCBU%2BjA9Lq0F05N%2FVII0zoD1rft2hX42nRTpqH%2Fk2iVyafK5avikgHRSJREYjh3Mm83%2BrdiR9ZTFSpqK5Pcu2vfO%2FlgyDRwdEgPXNJuxcmzSNI7Z0Zm3l95%2B7rNadJ4FvQ8NP3u0xEz3OeJhK79%2FnnMd1Ft5doOSeO8EKY5p3ltNw9mDtOWbzamhQD34e3EgxAcWgbqU0vCjxKEb8vsvSf06QaGQ6XX1QKH5hMEsT8%2B%2Bm%2FJ9t4Xf8L3%2FeympS%2BvJfPttobhXtzJSui2G7lLjaEkoAftl6ftIVkCQEovoHczwU%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=xxxxxxx&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=xxxxxx&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=xxxxxxxxxxx%2F20171030%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

**This is the response i'm getting after wget**

```
Resolving prod-04-2014-tasks.s3.amazonaws.com (prod-04-2014-tasks.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.225.104
Connecting to prod-04-2014-tasks.s3.amazonaws.com (prod-04-2014-tasks.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.225.104|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-10-30 11:24:11 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host: command not found
X-Amz-Date=xxxxxxxxxxx: command not found
X-Amz-Expires=600: command not found
X-Amz-Algorithm=xxxxxxxxxx: command not found
X-Amz-Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxx%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request: command not found
X-Amz-Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: command not found
[2]   Exit 127                X-Amz-Algorithm=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[3]   Exit 127                X-Amz-Date=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[4]   Exit 127                X-Amz-SignedHeaders=xxxxxxx
[5]-  Exit 127                X-Amz-Expires=600
[6]+  Exit 127                X-Amz-Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx%2F20171030%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
```

Is there any alternative way to download the above URL from terminal?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can able to download the object from the presigned S3 url. The problem solved for me from the below command.

> wget -O text.zip "https://presigned-s3-url"

After unzipping text.zip, I could see my files.

Comment: Also try using `wget --content-disposition "https://url"` to use the original filename. Especially handy when downloading multiple files and you don't want to specify individual filenames for each, or you want to keep the original filenames.

Answer (score 6):

You need to quote the url.  That is, instead of:

```
wget URL
```

You need:

```
wget 'URL'
```

The URL contains characters that have special meaning to the shell, such as `&`.  This is the source both of the failure to download the URL and all of the subsequent errors you are seeing.

Comment: I have tried with the quotes .Even on wget 'URL' or  wget "URL" it reports  the same . and assign the url to a variable and checked it. it reports the same. ` link=url; wget -i $link `

Comment: It absolutely does not have the same behavior when using quotes.  I obviously can't test it exactly, since your URL includes credentials that you have anonymized, but if I copy the URL from your question and run `wget -O somefile '...URL...'`, I don't get any of those "command not found" errors. I do get a `400 Bad Request` response from the server, but that's expected given the invalid authentication.

Comment: regarding a 400 Bad Request response, also consider that the token might time out earlier than specified expiration time, if the URL was not presigned using credentials from an IAM user  
- AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) instance profile: Valid up to 6 hours
- AWS Security Token Service (STS): Valid up to 36 hours...  
- IAM user: Valid up to 7 days when using AWS Signature Version 4  

[Why is my presigned URL for an Amazon S3 bucket expiring before the expiration time that I specified?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/)

Answer (score 0):

- try

I have tried `wget URL`, `wget 'URL'`, and `wget "URL"`, but none of them worked for downloading files with AWS S3 authentication parameters using wget in the `Linux terminal`.

but in mac osx command is ok. the wget url command exec in golang is ok.

- solved

I found a solution to this problem, which is to `escape the & character` in the URL using a backslash.

for example:

the original url is 'http://host/bucket/xxx.m3u8?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256`&`X-Amz-Credential=xxxx%2F20231117%2Fcn-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request`&`X-Amz-Date=20231117T015543Z`&`X-Amz-Expires=86400`&`X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host`&`X-Amz-Signature=xxxx'

the escaped url is 'http://host/bucket/xxx.m3u8?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256`\&`X-Amz-Credential=xxxx%2F20231117%2Fcn-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request`\&`X-Amz-Date=20231117T015543Z`\&`X-Amz-Expires=86400`\&`X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host`\&`X-Amz-Signature=xxxx'

- reason

This allows wget to execute properly. In the shell, the & character is used to `run commands in the background`, so by escaping it, the shell treats it as a regular character.